# Phpstorm 9 crash while indexing

Tags: java, php, phpstorm

I'm having an issue with PhpStorm 9 during indexing, just after startup, since yesterday : The IDE totally crash and after 10-15 seconds all I can do is rebooting.

I tried to upgrade from 141.2462 to 142.4912 but I have the same issue.

```
java -version                                                             
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.15.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)


javac -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
javac 1.8.0_60
```

I also removed the ~/.WebIde90 and ~/.WebIde95 folders.

I'm on Ubuntu 15.04.

Thanks for your help

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

I exactly had the same problem the culprit was the **MultiMarkdown** **plugin**, it crashes Phpstorm when loading. I disabled it and everything is back to normal.

**Tips on how to disable it since you can't open phpstorm as it crashes when loading:**

1. Open a text file(anything exept a .md file)  in phpstorm through terminal:

   `pstorm path/to/some/random/txt/file.txt`
2. Open File > Settings > Plugins
3. Uncheck **MultiMarkdown**
4. Restart

Comment: Thanks for your response and your time.

Unfortunately, it still try to index files and then crash... I don't have enough 
time to access the settings.